# Django ,How to show image on the board in templates?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to use like this

[image]

I'm making a bulltein board like the image.

I can show image in detail page. But i can't show image bulletin board list(index page).

How do I add images to the bulletin board list?

**toy/models.py**

```
class NewBornProduct(models.Model):
  type = models.ForeignKey(Type,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.CharField(,max_length=30)
  content = models.TextField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  price = models.IntegerField(null=False)


class NewBornProductImage(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(NewBornProduct,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="newborn/%Y/%m/%d")
   def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
      self.image.delete()
      return models.Model.delete(self, using=using, keep_parents=keep_parents)
```

**toy/views.py**

```
def newborn(request):
   obj = NewBornProduct.objects.all()
   return render(request,'toy/newborn.html',{'obj':obj})
```

**toy/newborn.html**

```
{% for post in obj %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{post.id}}</th>
        <th> i want to show image here!</th>    <-------- Here!
        <th>
            <a href="{% url 'toy:newborndetail' post.id %}">{{post.name}}</a>
        </th>
        <th>{{post.price}}</th>
        <th>{{post.amount}}</th>
        <th>{{post.pub_date}}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I do not know how to call the image because the other is fine

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which image ? Your product model can have zero to many images...

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers,  product model's object have many images.  i want to use {% for i in obj|slice:":1" %}

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers,  In detail page, i use like this {% for i in obj.newbornproductimage_set.all %}
    <img src="{{i.image.url}}" width=30%>
   {% endfor %}

Comment: @minsoo If possible (depends on the desired relation) change your models. Remove the ForeignKey from the Image model and add a new ForeignKey(Image) to the Product. Then you can simply access it by post.image.image

Comment: @zypro could you say more detail? It is difficult to understand because English is not accustomed.

Comment: @minsoo see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what yoy want is "the first image if there's one":

```
{% for post in obj %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{post.id}}</th>
        <th>
        {% with post.newbornproductimage_set.first as img %}
          {% if img %}<img src="{{ img.image.url }}" />{% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        </th>    
        <th>
            <a href="{% url 'toy:newborndetail' post.id %}">{{post.name}}</a>
        </th>
        <th>{{post.price}}</th>
        <th>{{post.amount}}</th>
        <th>{{post.pub_date}}</th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also note that:

1/ your markup is wrong, you should be using `td`, not `th` (`th` is a table header)

2/ naming your products queryset `obj` and products instances `post` is not going to help wrt/ readabilty/maintainability. You should rename `obj` to `products` (plural, denotes a collection) and `post` to `product`.

Comment: @minsoo sorry, there was a typo, the reverse related accessor should be "newbornproductimage_set", not "image_set" (fixed the snippet). FWIW you can test this in the django shell.

Comment: Thanks ! sincerely. You are GOD.Thanks to you, I can proceed to the training project.

Comment: Glad I could help - and feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)